# How to match impedance when driving 75ohm differential video amp with single ended RS-170 video output?

Tags: video

I am trying to feed RS-170 video signal from a single ended amp to a differential 75 ohms video amp. When I connected RS-170 signal to + of the differential and RS-170 return to - of differential, video had a lot of flickering and noise - maybe impedance matching problem? I think it is matched 75 ohm, but maybe I am wrong. The video amp is AD8023 from Analog Device. The two systems' GNDs are connected (driving side and receiving side) via other connection, but not shown in the drawing below.

What's the best way to connect TSG350 to 75 ohms differential video amp(37.5ohm into each +/- inputs of the amp)? Please advise.

[image]

Comment: We have no idea what opamp you are using there, what the bandwidth requirements are, if they are met and how the signals look like. You might want to provide those along with some measurements

Comment: I believe the video amp is AD8023 from Analog Device. And the signal is RS-170, plain old analog video format.

Comment: Add additional information in your question, not in the comments. Also, why would you not simply use a diff-amp transmitter?

Comment: The fact that you did not connect the shielding on the right side to ground tells me that you have no clue. I suggest that you search the internet for circuits that perform this function.

Comment: @Humble1: there is much room for quality degradation in component video, to debug such a situation you look at the actual signal and determine its quality and try to figure out what happened to it and if it still complies. Obviously something is wrong with the signal, otherwise you would not have the noise, so it is *not* just a component signal, but only something similar to it.

Comment: The two GNDs (left/right of coax) are connected via other connector.

Comment: Your 37.5 ohm resistors should actually be 150 ohms each (twice 75, not half).  Note that at the op amp the voltage across the + and - inputs should be zero.  So the 37.5 ohm resistor on the shield appears in parallel, not series, with the other 37.5 ohm resistor (center conductor to ground).  Thus, I think your impedance at the 8023 will look like 18.75 ohms, which won't work.  You could also just ground the coax on both sides (best),  put a 75 ohm resistor in parallel across the lines, and use a high input impedance (standard non-inverting) op amp configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your differential video amp's input really *is* 75Ω...

To minimize reflections the 75Ω cable needs to be terminated with 75Ω. The differential amp's input is 37.5Ω per leg, so you need another 37.5Ω in series to pad it out to 75Ω.

Both ends must share a common ground, so if the sending and receiving ends are remote then the cable should be connected to ground at both ends.

The differential amp is expecting to see 37.5Ω on each of its inputs. A different impedance on the inverting input may change its gain. However with the signal only going to one input the amplitude is already halved, so increasing the gain may be desirable.

If the differential amp circuit is similar to what you have shown then connecting the inverting input to ground may work. If not then terminate it with a 37.5Ω resistor, and (If possible) increase the signal amplitude at the transmitting end.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJJGlB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>